# UICKeyChainStore not saving data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) from following the docs:

```
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
UICKeyChainStore *store = [UICKeyChainStore keyChainStore];
[store setData:json forKey:@"user"];
[store synchronize];
```

(I breakpointed and there's data inside `data`)

and then elsewhere in my code:

```
UICKeyChainStore *store = [UICKeyChainStore keyChainStore];

NSData *user = [store dataForKey:@"user"];
NSLog(@"User: %@", user);
if(user == nil){
```

`user` is always `nil`! I'm new to iOS, so I'm just trying to make sure I'm not doing anything too silly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I breakpointed and there's data inside data" But did you check json is not nil?

If there is a problem with the format of your data then it won't get converted in JSONObjectWithData.

Whenever you use a function that takes an NSError as a parameter you should pass one in and examine it afterwards, don't just pass nil.